# without using the “?” sign how to pass variable value in url using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

I want to pass the variable value in URL using javascript without using the "?" sign.

i can do this in php easily but dont know how to do this in js

For ex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var track_no;
    function onload() { 
        track_no = document.getElementById('track_no');
    }
    function kk(){
        alert(track_no.value);

          var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://google.com/`value of track_no enterd by user`;");
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
</script>


<body onload="onload();">
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="track_no"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="kk();"/>
</body>
```

NOTE that in iframe i don't want to use "?" like this

```
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://google.com/?"+track_no+";");
```

I want to pass a value directly after the "/" sign without using "?"

```
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://google.com/12345(the value of track_no)");
```

:)

Comment: Do you want the query to be something understandable (like "?q="), or just a plain question mark followed by the string?

Comment: How do you do this in PHP. More importantly what does this have to do with PHP anyway?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the question mark? The question mark indicates exactly the sort of thing you want - URL parameters. Is the problem that you don't want to add multiple query parameters manually, or what?

Comment: Question edited!!
@CertainPerformance no, i want don't want to use "?" sign,I  just want to use value directly after "/" sign

Comment: @pujara Why not? Don't gimp yourself from using a particular key on the keyboard for no reason, that's silly

Comment: @CertainPerformance the url i am passing the value is not accepting "?" sign, so i need to pass the value directly after the "/" sign

Comment: @AbidHasan in php i can use get or post method and pass the value to the url, it will be easily done in php, but i am doing this purly in html and js without using php

Answer (score 0):

You need `kk` to be able to access `track_no`'s value. If you really need to select the element immediately for some reason, then just wait until the element is selected to attach the handler to the button (remove your inline-eval-onclick handlers, attach Javascript with Javascript instead):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const track_no = document.getElementById('track_no');
  document.querySelector('input[type="button"]')
    .addEventListener('click', () => {
    const searchText = track_no.value;
    const ifrm = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
    ifrm.src = 'https://www.google.com/' + searchText;
    ifrm.style.width = "640px";
    ifrm.style.height = "480px";
  });
});
```

Comment: It didn't load the iframe, the click event has no effect

Comment: Then you have some other problem you haven't mentioned: works here https://jsfiddle.net/960r8abs/

Comment: yeah, there was some mistake in my other part of code, it worked!! Thanks